# When do we say the uncountable sum $\sum \alpha_ie_i$ of vectors in non-separable Hilbert space is convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let {$e_i$} be an uncountable orthonormal set in some non-separable Hilbert space. Then, when we say the uncountable sum $\sum \alpha_ie_i$ is convergent. ($\alpha_i$'s are scalars)

Answer (score 0):

The sum $\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_ie_i$ converges if the set
$$\left\{\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_je_j:J\subset I,J\text{ finite}\right\}$$
has exactly one accumulation point.

Comment: What is an "accumulation point of a set"? Suppose all terms are zero; then the set is $\{0\}$. Not much accumulation, do you conclude it's not convergent?